# How to re-use autotools Makefile.am files

Tags: makefile, autotools

I am using autotools to help me with Makefiles.

What I am trying to do:

I am trying to make one Makefile.am to control 1-n projects. i.e A root dir containing the autotools stuff configure, configure.ac etc. No code is in the root dir. So somehow I have to tell the Makefile.am that it has to start compiling project x, y, z...

Is it possible to have a root Makefile.am and a Makefile.am in each project, so I can use the root Makefile.am to compile all projects and if needed, I can use Makefile.am in project x to only compile project x ?

If possible how can I do this ?

BR
DarkRoast

Comment: Your subject is very broad, perhaps make it a bit more specific like "How to re-use autotools Makefile.am files"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly how recursive make is designed. Simply put, in the root `Makefile.am`,

```
SUBDIRS = x y z
```

and then put the rules for compiling projects x, y, and z in `x/Makefile.am`, `y/Makefile.am`, and `z/Makefile.am`. Then, to compile all the projects, run `make` in the root directory. To compile only project x, change to directory `x` and run `make` there.

Comment: Hi ptomato. My Makfile.am in the root now only contains SUBDIRS = x y z. When I run make it compiles x y and z but all the .o files are in the root dir and the executable is not made, unless I run make in e.x dir x. Why is that ?

Comment: Do I need to make autoscan etc. in each subfolder or do I only need a Makefile.am in each subfolder ?